# How can i get the string including HTML element after highlighting the text in HTML using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say, I highlighted this text `The Title is Superman and Batman` in my page.

How can i get the text including it's HTML element?

Based on my example, I should get this:

```
The Title is <i>Superman</i> and <i>Batman</i>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery html selector to get the value with HTML selector.

HTML:

```
 <div id="test">this is my <i>test</i></div>
```

JS:

```
 $('#test').html()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take the values adding a class or id.

HTML:

```
<div class="test"><i>Superman</i></div>
<div class="test"><i>Batman</i></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.test').html()
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TGwGg/1/)

Comment: from the string of my page "The Title is <i>Superman</i> and <i>Batman</i>"

what if I highlight only "man</i> and <i>Bat" in my page, is it possible to get that exact string?

Comment: @KennethDeloso What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Since everyone is requiring OP to use jQuery, here's the native JS equivalent. You can select the html content of an element like so :

```
var html = document.getElementById('text-container').innerHTML;
```

You might want to redisplay all the HTML from the container as different values, eg. as HTML markup, as text, as HTML-encoded text. With that I mean HTML entities (eg. `&gt;` for `>` (greater than sign)). Here are the methods for displaying different types of output each time:
Here's a variable for the subsequent code:

```
var target = document.getElementById('text-output'); // for later
```

#### 1. HTML in a container element

- Output: Rendered HTML
- Javascript:

```
target.innerHTML = html;
```

#### 2. Text in a container element

- Output: Text, HTML entities encoded
- Javascript:

```
// will automatically encode HTML entities
var text = document.createTextNode(html); 
target.innerHTML = text;
```

#### 3. HTML in a `textarea` element

- Output: Text, HTML entities non-encoded
- Javascript:

```
yourTextArea.value = html;
```

#### 4. Text in a `textarea` element

- Output: Text, HTML entities encoded
- Javascript:

```
 // The virtual container automatically encodes entities when its .innerHTML
 // method is called after appending a textnode.
 var virtualContainer = document.createElement('div');
 var text = document.createTextNode(html); 
 virtualContainer.appendChild(text);
 yourTextArea.value = virtualContainer.innerHTML;
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/mozibezi/1/edit

**PS:** It is impossible to display the output from #4 in a non-form input.